For which integer n, is there a circle inscribing n gridpoints
I was browsing the internet and I found a question in German. I was not really satisfied nor really understood the anwser proposed there, and would like to get some further insight in this problem. I was looking at the Schinzel Theorem for example, but could not really use it to solve the question. I would be really glad for someone providing me with a solution.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

For completeness sake it would be good if you edited in the actual problem

I'll do my best to explain the solution given on the link you referenced. The first step is to consider the set $S$ of all lines that are perpendicular bisectors to $2$ integer points. The main technicallity of the argument, is showing that there's a point $p\in\mathbb R^2$ that is in none of the lines in $S$. Let's see how we can finish the argument assuming we have such $p$. First notice that $p$ cannot be an integer point, since $(a,b)$ is in the perpendicular bisector of $(a+1,b)$ and $(a-1,b)$. Therefore, there is some circle around $p$ with no integer point on its interior; that shows the case $n=0$. Now imagine that for some radius $r$ you have exactly $k$ points on the ball $B(p,r)$, if you increase $r$ enough, the number of points on the ball must increase; if it increased by two or more, that means that at some point you had two integer points on the boundary of the ball; but this implies that $p$ is at the same distance of two integer points; which can't be, since that would imply $p$ is on thei perpendicular bisector; which by construction of $p$ doesn't happen; this implies that the number of points increases by one each time.
Therefore; we just have proving the existence of $p$; the solution on th link claims that any countable set of lines cannot cover the plane i.e. there's a point in none of them. They also claim that this is easily provable, which I don't agree. A pretty direct proof (and simple modulo the BCT) is via Baire's category theorem since lines are closed sets of empty interior; so a countable union of them still has empty interior, so in particular it's not the whole space. I don't know if it's possible to come up with a simple proof of this fact that doesn't invoke Baire's category theorem.

Yes, it is. Consider the angular coefficients of these lines (considered up to adding $\infty$). These form a countable subset of the extended real, so there is a line whose angular coefficients is different than that of all the segment bisector you considered. Now, take such a line (any line will work) and realize it intersect each of the bisector in exactly one point. So the complement of the intersection of the line is the complement of a countable set in a continuum set and therefor there will be a point outside all of the intersections. This point will work

@AlessandroFenu That's such a pretty argument
